# Layout not showing on device

Tags: xamarin

when i update my layout of xamarin app it dosent show on deployment on my device. It always shows the default layout i'm using xamarin with visual studio 2015

Comment: What layout are you using in SetContentView?

Answer (score 0):

Open the **Build --> Configuration Manager** menu in Visual Studio and check if "Deploy" is activated for your project.